# Fedora kernel headers

Tags: linux, fedora

Чтобы установить драйвер nvidia на Fedora 31 мне нужны последние хидеры на ядро 5.4.17-200.fc31.x86_64.

`sudo dnf install kernel-5.4.17-200.fc31.x86_64 kernel-core-5.4.17-200.fc31.x86_64 kernel-headers-5.4.17-200.fc31.x86_64 kernel-modules-5.4.17-200.fc31.x86_64`

```
Package kernel-5.4.17-200.fc31.x86_64 is already installed.
Package kernel-core-5.4.17-200.fc31.x86_64 is already installed.
No match for argument: kernel-headers-5.4.17-200.fc31.x86_64
Package kernel-modules-5.4.17-200.fc31.x86_64 is already installed.
Error: Unable to find a match: kernel-headers-5.4.17-200.fc31.x86_64
```

Иначе акмод не собирается. Потерял закладку как искать хидеры и ядра последние. Подскажет кто-нибудь ?

Comment: ну, не выложили пакета с заголовочными файлами для данной версии: https://mirror.yandex.ru/fedora/linux/updates/31/Everything/x86_64/Packages/k/ . пишите багрепорт.

Comment: А есть идеи где могут быть в другом месте собраны хидеры в рпм ? есть же где-наверное мб в репозитории каком-нибудь стороннем. Ждать как-то грустно.

Comment: [ну и между прочим](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Core/6/html/Release_Notes/ar01s07s07.html). как там написано, для сборки модулей к программе linux вам нужен пакет kernel-devel, а не kernel-headers

Comment: Спасибо большое ! акмод встал с kernel-devel. Установить последнюю версию можно с помощью sudo yum install "kernel-devel-uname-r == $(uname -r)"

Много благодарен